# Is there a way to incorporate a countdown timer into an R function?

Tags: r

I want to incorporate a countdown timer into an R function that I am writing to record the behavioural response of animals to smells so that the user knows how long an experiment has left to run.

I have found a package called `countdown` that I think could be useful, which can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/gadenbuie/countdown). When using this package I cannot get the `countdown_fullscreen` function to operate as I need for my function - it doesn't display the countdown in the viewer pane and nor does it begin automatically. Both of these issues decrease the experiment accuracy.

This is the code I am using for my function:

```
record_data = function(x) {
require(tictoc) #load required packages
require(countdown) 

timer = readline("Observation time: ")
timer = as.numeric(timer)
countdown::countdown_fullscreen(timer)

while(T){       #open infinite while loop
    tic()       #start timer
    input_state=readline("State input: ")  #allow for entry of state
    if(input_state %in% 1:5){    #check if it's acceptable 
        elapsed=toc()            #if it is then end timer and record data
        write.table(cbind(input_state,elapsed$toc-elapsed$tic),'results.txt',col.names=F,row.names=F,quote=F,append=T)
    }else if(input_state=='t'){  #if input is 't' 
        break                    #break out of while loop
    }else if(input_state <1 | input_state > 5 & input_state!='t'){ #if input is not and accepted state AND is not 't'
     print('thats not an allowed state- please try another')
     } 
}
```

I expect that the timer would be displayed in viewer and begin automatically, but this is not the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the countdown package.  But one option may be to use a tcltk progress bar

```
library(tcltk)

timer = 10
pb <- tkProgressBar("Timer")
start = Sys.time()
while(TRUE) {
  elapsed = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), start, units = 'secs'))
  remaining = timer - elapsed
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  setTkProgressBar(pb, remaining/timer, label = sprintf("Time remaining: %i seconds", round(remaining)))
  if (remaining <= 0) break
}
Sys.sleep(2)
close(pb)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply dww. I am not sure how I would incorporate this into my function above and it doesn't give me a graphical display for the user to see how much time is remaining in an experiment. For example, in my code above the user could specify the experiment would last 12 minutes and I would need a visual representation of the time remaining. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it doesn't give a graphical display of time remaining - that is excactly what it does do.   But no problem -  hopefully someone else can give you a solution closer to wht you want.

Comment: I say that because it displays nothing - where should the graphical output be displayed in RStudio? My reply wasn’t a criticism of your solution, for which I am very grateful.

Comment: The timer will be in a pop-up window.  I added a screenshot

Comment: Many thanks for the screenshot dww. I have looked at this with fresh eyes this morning and it seems my computer was blocking this pop up, which I have now rectified. How can this be incorporated into the code in my original post? Thanks.